# Displaying large output on terminal window

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
int a[10000];
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
{
   a[i]=i; cout<<a[i]<<endl;
}
```

Suppose this is the code and on the terminal screen I need all outputs (0-9999) But it only displays (9704-9999) at the end

I want to see all the numbers on the terminal window but it removes the upper part of the data. I guess I have to change some settings.

Comment: Please show a [mre] work the full code you are using, the output you expect and the actual output you are getting

Comment: Edit your question, don't post code in the comments

Comment: if any answer helps you, please consider clicking the green checkmark to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and do not post a "thank you" comment. That's how this community works. Also take a 1-minute [tour] to understand more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the *console buffering*. Depending on which terminal you're using it'll be different. For example on Windows [conhost.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Console#Windows_NT_and_Windows_CE) is the default console used by cmd and PowerShell. Just click the icon on the top left > Properties > Layout and set **Screen Buffer Size** to a large enough number

[image: Conhost]

But the better solution would be [**redirecting to file**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)), because no one wants to read 10000 lines on the console, and there's no guarantee that the console will have a buffer of infinite length or length of more than 10000 lines. `conhost` for example only supports maximum 9999 lines so you'll miss at least the command you typed and the first output line. Besides that'll often remove other commands' output from the history which is undesirable

Either do that from the command line with the redirection operator `>`

```
yourapp.exe >output.txt
```

or save to file directly from your code